# Word VBA insert plain text spaces before and after all hyperlinks

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, hyperlink, insert

I want to add spaces after timestamps, in a transcript which pasted with no space between the timestamp hyperlinks and the surrounding text.

`oLink.Range.InsertBefore " "` inserts plain text, but `oLink.Range.InsertAfter " "` appends the added text formatted as hyperlink - which means anything typed after the space is also formatted as hyperlink text.

How do I insert a space after, in the underlying style?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your post to show sample doc. I've tested `oLink.Range.InsertAfter " "` on Word 365 without issues.

Comment: @taller
 Are you saying inserted spaces are not in hyperlink style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I inserted plain text after hyperlinks

```
Sub H___AddSpace_PlainTextBeforeAndAfterHyperlinks()

Dim oLink As Hyperlink

'======= R___PRESELECTED_RANGE_SetAndRESELECTafterLOOPS macro
'1.===== Name pre-selected range (if LOOP is going to be executed or called on a TABLE) R___PRESELECTED_RANGE_SetAndRESELECTafterLOOPS Macro
    Dim PRESELECTED_RANGE As Range
        
    '1a.________ if no selection, msgbox select all, dont select or exit
    If Selection.Range = "" Then
        SELECT_RANGE = MsgBox("Select whole document?" & vbNewLine & _
                "Cancel to make selection manually!" & vbNewLine & _
                "No will run only on the selection type the cursor is in.", _
                vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton2)
            If SELECT_RANGE = vbYes Then
                Selection.WholeStory 'selects whole document - then save selection below
            ElseIf SELECT_RANGE = vbCancel Then
                Exit Sub
            End If 'SELECT_RANGE options (will continue with no selection made if yes or cancel not pressed)
    End If

    '1b.________ set preselected range
    Set PRESELECTED_RANGE = Selection.Range 'needs to be set after every preselected range dim, and after every loop


'2.======= Loop
     For Each oLink In PRESELECTED_RANGE.Hyperlinks

'2a.---- insert space before (inerts as plain text)
    oLink.Range.InsertBefore " "

'2b.----- INSERT SPACE AFTER
    oLink.Range.Select
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1 'COLLAPSES TO END
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend 'select following letter
        Selection.Copy 'copy following character
        Selection.TypeText Text:=" " 'type space over letter
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting) 'paste the copied letter after the space
    
Next oLink
Set oLink = Nothing

'3.====== reselect range for exit or next action (in MAIN macro, before LOOP macros called, +after each "next" command)
PRESELECTED_RANGE.Select 'add after every "next" - for exit or next procedure

MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: And, at the start is left as an exercise for the student?

Comment: @Charles Kenyon  - ??? If you are referring to the "preselected range" code, no it is not _"at the start is left as an exercise for the student"._  Any more than _"... in activedocument.hyperlinks"_ would be.  I prefer to post code that works, rather than snippets requiring people to resolve problems using them.  That code stops loops failing when operated on manually selected ranges.  It took me weeks to figure out the solution.  If there is a better way perhaps you could helpfully suggest it.